# How change navbar link outline color on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navbar

At first, I've just wanted to change the background color of a dropdown menu at the navbar. 
I wanted that because the default background color is grey and I wanted to make it transparent.

To achieve that, I customized `bootstrap.css` using the link provided by bootstrap (`/bootstrap/customize`)

I've changed `@navbarLinkBackgroundActive` to `TRANSPARENT` instead of `@lightGrey`
I also changed `@navbarLinkColor` to `@black`.

Below there's the before and after the changes:

BEFORE:
http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/7027/stackdropdownoriginal.jpg

AFTER:
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/7503/stackdropdownalterado.jpg

As you can see, the background color has changed.

But now, I have another problem. I want to remove the white outline of the link!
I played with the different variables on bootstrap customize page but I couldn't achieve it correctly.

Changing `@navbarBackgroundHighlight` to `@black` will "remove" this white outline (though it still ugly), but it also mess with the navbar creating a black straight line under it.

Also, is there som way to change these color besides using bootstrap customize page?
Is there a way to to overwrite this color properties on my .css?

Answer (score 1):

That "white outline" is really a white `text-shadow`. Just set it to `none`.

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    text-shadow:none;
}
```